Webpage not updating content when mobile screen resizes
I have created a webpage and made it responsive only for horizontal phone screens. So i've tried to implement eventlisteners. If the phone screen is vertical, I will not display the content, however if I flip it to be horizontal, it will. I tested it on chrome responsive dev tools and it worked perfectly. However when I try it on an actual mobile phone, it does not update when I flip my phone screen horizontally and I am stuck with the black screen.
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useStore } from "@/store";
import PracticeContent from "./PracticeContent"; // Make sure this path is correct

const ClientSidePractice = () => {
  const [isLandscape, setIsLandscape] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const { setFullscreen } = useStore();
  const isPhone = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.innerWidth <= 932;

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOrientationChange = () => {
      setIsLandscape(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight);
    };

    handleOrientationChange(); 

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleOrientationChange);
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", handleOrientationChange);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleOrientationChange);
      window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", handleOrientationChange);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPhone) {
      setFullscreen(true);
    }
  }, [isPhone, setFullscreen]);

  if (isPhone && !isLandscape) {
    return (
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-[100vw] h-[100vh] bg-black text-white px-4">
        <p className="text-xl text-center">Please flip your phone to landscape mode</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <PracticeContent />;
};

export default ClientSidePractice;


"use client";

import React from "react";
import { useStore } from "@/store";
import GameTable from "./GameTable";
import UserInputs from "./UserInput";
import BalanceDisplay from "./BalanceDisplay";
import ShoeDeck from "./ShoeDeck";
import SessionButton from "./SessionsButton";

const PracticeContent: React.FC = () => {
  const { fullscreen } = useStore();
  const isPhone = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.innerWidth <= 932;

  return (
    <main className="text-black dark:text-white w-full h-full flex flex-col py-5 pr-5">
      {fullscreen ? (
        <section className="flex w-full h-[100vh] relative">
          <GameTable isPhone={isPhone} />
        </section>
      ) : (
        <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row w-full h-full">
          <section className="flex flex-col pl-[10px] gap-y-2 w-full md:w-1/3">
            <ShoeDeck />
            <BalanceDisplay />
            <div className="">
              <UserInputs />
            </div>
            <div className="md:hidden flex">
              <SessionButton />
            </div>
          </section>
          <section className="flex flex-col px-2 md:px-7 w-full h-[100vh]">
            <GameTable isPhone={isPhone} />
          </section>
        </div>
      )}
    </main>
  );
};

export default PracticeContent;



you could try using a key like.. "isLandscape" to force a rerender. for testing purposes use window.innerWidth as a key, so you can see if it solves your problem.
